# How to delete a django object inline with jquery

Tags: django, django-models

To delete an object I inherit from DeleteView which has 3 steps (user clicks on delete, goes to confirm page, click yes again, redirected to success page) How can I make it more inline (user clicks delete, alert window pops up asking user to confirm, user confirms, the object is gone, user is still on the same page)

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/recipientbank/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RecipientBankAccountDeleteView.as_view(model=RecipientBankAccount)),
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/recipientbank/delete/(\d+)/success/$',recipientbank_deleted,name='recipientbank_deleted'),

class RecipientBankAccountDeleteView(DeleteView):
    form_class = RecipientBankAccountForm
    success_url='success'

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


def recipientbank_deleted(request, username, public_profile_field=None,template_name='main/recipientbankaccount_deleted.html',extra_context=None):
    return render(request, template_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use django-piston to create RESTful APIs and make an AJAX call from your page to delete your django objects.

You can read about RESTful here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

and django-piston here: https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home

I've heard that you could achieve this with Generic Views starting django version 1.3, but I haven't used it.